# Disqus makes IE8 go into Compatibility Mode "Hard Assert". Any fix?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, disqus, ie8-compatibility-mode

After testing I have found Disqus makes IE8 go into Compatibility Mode "Hard Assert". When I remove it it stops the behavior and stays in Standard Mode. Due to the fact that IE8 is tide to Windows XP IE8 will be around awhile. Worth fixing. Anybody know a fix for this? I already contacted Disqus support. I am not hopeful of a quick response.

Comment: We're not able to reproduce this today on your site, are you still getting the error?

Comment: I am also having the same problem on my site.

Comment: For now I have just removed the JS loader using IE comments (`<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->`). Would be nice to get a fix from Disqus though.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if any of you were able to find (or get) a fix for this. Or another workaround. Unfortunately I am stuck with an XP IE8 environment as well. To see the issue in action you can check out my bare bones [Disqus test page](https://googledrive.com/host/0Bz81OpG5fJCHOVYxME9WWHlwODQ/)

Comment: I am encountering this issue, as well. Has anyone found a fix?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use CC's to target IE8 Disqus just say...

```
#disqus_thread {
display:none; /* IE8 */
}
:root #disqus_thread {
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That is not the case. Remove the css remove the issue.